# How to prove $\mathbf{1}^\top\mathbf{Q}^+\mathbf{Q}=\mathbf{1}^\top$, where $\mathbf{Q}$ is any element-wise squared correlation matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, correlation, pseudoinverse, idempotents

Let $(X_1,…,X_n)$ be a random vector with $0<\prod_{j=1}^n\text{Var}(X_j)<∞$.

Let $\mathbf{Q}=(\mathbf{q}_{1},…,\mathbf{q}_{n})=(ρ_{jk}^2)_{n×n}$, where $ρ_{jk}$ is the [Pearson correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient) between $X_j$ and $X_k$. How to prove or disprove

$$\mathbf{1}^\top\mathbf{Q}^+\mathbf{Q}=\mathbf{1}^\top$$

where $\mathbf{Q}^+$ is the [Moore-Penrose inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) of $\mathbf{Q}$ and $\mathbf{1}^\top$ is a row vector of ones?

$$$$

It seems that when any row or column vectors in $\mathbf{Q}$ are linearly dependent, they must be equal. If it is true, let $\mathbf{H}_{n×n}=(\mathbf{h}_1,…,\mathbf{h}_r,\mathbf{0},…,\mathbf{0})^\top$ be the [reduced row echelon form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form#Reduced_row_echelon_form) of $\mathbf{Q}$, where $r=\text{rank}(\mathbf{Q})$; and there is $\mathbf{h}_{j}^\top\mathbf{h}_{k}=0$ for all $j\neq k$.

Then, let the column indices of the leading ones in each nonzero rows of $\mathbf{H}$ be $j_1,…,j_r$, and let

$$\mathbf{F}_{n×r}=(\mathbf{q}_{j_1},...,\mathbf{q}_{j_r}),\;
\mathbf{G}_{r×n}=(\mathbf{h}_1,...,\mathbf{h}_r)^\top$$

According to [rank factorization from reduced row echelon forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_factorization#Rank_factorization_from_reduced_row_echelon_forms), we have $\mathbf{Q}=\mathbf{FG}$

According to [construction of Moore–Penrose inverse by rank decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Rank_decomposition), we have

$$\mathbf{Q}^+=\mathbf{G}^\top(\mathbf{GG^\top})^{-1}(\mathbf{F^\top F})^{-1}\mathbf{F}^\top$$

Thus,
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
& \mathbf{1}^\top\mathbf{Q}^+\mathbf{Q} 
= \mathbf{1}^\top\mathbf{G}^\top(\mathbf{GG^\top})^{-1}\mathbf{G} \\
& = \mathbf{1}^\top
\begin{bmatrix}
  \mathbf{h}_1 & \cdots & \mathbf{h}_r 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  \mathbf{h}_1^\top\mathbf{h}_1 & \cdots &
    \mathbf{h}_1^\top\mathbf{h}_r \\
  \vdots &  \ddots &  \vdots \\
  \mathbf{h}_r^\top\mathbf{h}_1 & \cdots & 
    \mathbf{h}_r^\top\mathbf{h}_r \\
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \mathbf{h}_1^\top \\
  \vdots \\
\mathbf{h}_r^\top \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
& = \mathbf{1}^\top\sum_{i=0}^r (\mathbf{h}_i^\top\mathbf{h}_i)^{-1} \mathbf{h}_i \mathbf{h}_i^\top = \mathbf{1}^\top
\end{split}
\end{equation}

where $\mathbf{h}_i^\top\mathbf{h}_i$ is the number of ones in $\mathbf{h}_i$ and $\mathbf{h}_i\mathbf{h}_i^\top$ is an $n×n$ block diagonal matrix with main-diagonal blocks of either ones or zeros.

Therefore, the question may turn into how to prove or disprove that, when any rows in $\mathbf{Q}$ are linearly dependent, they must be the same.

Comment: and what exactly is a Pearson correlation matrix of a random vector ? You mean an autocorrelation like $\text{Cov}(X,X)$ ? The wikipedia article does not have this, meaning this is not a standard mathematical term. You need to give a precise mathematical definition of your $\mathbf{R}$

Comment: @dezdichado A correlation matrix is SPSD with ones on the main diagonal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Schur product theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_product_theorem) tells that $\mathbf{Q}$ is positive semi-definite. Then by the property of Moore–Penrose pseudoinverse, $\mathbf{Q}^{+}\mathbf{Q} = \mathbf{Q}\mathbf{Q}^{+}$ is the orthogonal projection onto the range of $\mathbf{Q}$, yielding the following equivalence:

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{1}^{\top}\mathbf{Q}^{+}\mathbf{Q} = \mathbf{1}^{\top}
&\quad\iff\quad \mathbf{1} \in \operatorname{im}\mathbf{Q} = (\ker \mathbf{Q})^{\perp} \\
&\quad\iff\quad (\ker\mathbf{Q}) \perp \mathbf{1}
\end{align*}

We will establish the last relation using a probabilistic argument.

---

**Proof.** Replacing each $X_i$ by its standardization if necessary, we may assume $\mathsf{Var}(X_i) = 1$ for each $i$. Let $\mathbf{\Sigma}_X$ be the covariance matrix of $X$. Also, define the random vectors $\tilde{X}$ and $Y$ by

$$ \tilde{X} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{\Sigma}_X)
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
Y = \tilde{X}^{\circ 2} = (\tilde{X}_1^2, \ldots, \tilde{X}_n^2)^{\top}, $$

where $\circ$ denotes Hadamard/entrywise product. Then, as in the [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_product_theorem#Case_of_M_=_N) of Schur product theorem, we know that the covariance matrix $\mathbf{\Sigma}_Y$ of $Y$ is given by $ \mathbf{\Sigma}_Y = 2\mathbf{\Sigma}_X^{\circ 2} = 2\mathbf{Q} $. So, it suffices to show

$$ (\ker \mathbf{\Sigma}_Y) \perp \mathbf{1}. $$

To this end, assume $\mathbf{v} \in \ker \mathbf{\Sigma}_Y$. Then

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{v} \in \ker \mathbf{\Sigma}_Y
&\quad\implies\quad 
0 = \mathbf{v}^{\top}\mathbf{\Sigma}_Y\mathbf{v} = \mathsf{Var}(\mathbf{v}^{\top}Y) \\
&\quad\iff\quad
\mathbf{v}^{\top}Y = \mathsf{E}[\mathbf{v}^{\top}Y] = \mathbf{v}^{\top}\mathbf{1} \quad \text{a.s.} \\
&\quad\iff\quad
\mathbf{v}^{\top}(\mathbf{x}^{\circ 2}) = \mathbf{v}^{\top}\mathbf{1} \quad \text{for any } \mathbf{x} \in \operatorname{im}\mathbf{\Sigma}_X
\end{align*}

In particular, plugging $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0}$ shows that $\mathbf{v}^{\top}\mathbf{1} = 0$ and hence $\mathbf{v} \perp \mathbf{1}$. $\square$

---

**Addendum.** This argument actually proves a more general statement:

> **Theorem.** Let $\mathbf{A}$ be an $n\times n$ positive semi-definite matrix, and let $\mathbf{Q} = \mathbf{A}^{\circ 2}$ be the Hadamard/entrywise square of $\mathbf{A}$. Then
>
> $$ \mathbf{v}^{\top}\mathbf{Q}^+ \mathbf{Q} = \mathbf{v}^{\top}, $$
>
> where $\mathbf{v} = (a_{11}, a_{22}, \ldots, a_{nn})^{\top}$ is the main diagonal of $\mathbf{A}$.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. I have a question. Since $\mathbf{Q}^+\mathbf{Q}$ is an orthogonal projection,  $\mathbf1^\top\mathbf{Q}^+\mathbf{Q}=\mathbf{1}^\top$ (output of the projection applying to $\mathbf1^\top$ is itself) holds if and only if $\mathbf{1}\in\text{im}(\mathbf{Q}^\top\mathbf{Q})$ ($\mathbf1\in\text{im}\mathbf{Q}$ is not obviously). It seems $\text{im}(\mathbf{Q}^+\mathbf{Q})=\text{im}(\mathbf{Q})$, but how to prove it?

Comment: @woody, A [general theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Projectors) tells that $\mathbf{X}^+\mathbf{X}$ is an orthogonal projection onto the range of $\mathbf{X}^*$ for an arbitrary matrix $\mathbf{X}$. In our case, $\mathbf{Q}$ is symmetric and hence $\operatorname{im}\mathbf{Q}^*=\operatorname{im}\mathbf{Q}$, proving the claim.

Comment: For the last "$\Longleftrightarrow$", is it because $\mathbf{v}^\top Y=\mathbf{v}^\top(\mathbf{x}^{\circ2}), \forall\mathbf{v}\in\text{ker}\mathbf{\Sigma}_Y,\forall\mathbf{x}\in \text{im}\mathbf{\Sigma}_X$, and how to prove it?

Comment: @woody, The last equivalence actually holds for *any* $\mathbf{v}$. This equivalence is due to the fact that the distribution of $Y$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the Hausdorff measure on the subspace $\operatorname{im}\mathbf{\Sigma}_X$.

Comment: If this sounds too demanding, you can perhaps appeal to a more elementary argument using conditioning: $$\mathsf{P}(\mathbf{v}^{\top}Y=\mathbf{v}^{\top}\mathbf{1})=1\qquad\implies\qquad\lim_{\varepsilon\to0^+}\mathsf{P}(\mathbf{v}^{\top}Y=\mathbf{v}^{\top}\mathbf{1}\mid \|X\|\leq\varepsilon)=1, $$ and the last relation essentially tells that $\mathbf{v}^{\top}\mathbf{1}$ can be made arbitrarily small with probability one, which then becomes a deterministic truth $\mathbf{v}^{\top}\mathbf{1} =0$ since the left-hand side is non-random.

Answer (score 3):

We have $\mathbf1^\top Q^+Q=\mathbf1^\top$ if and only if the vector of ones lies inside the row space of $Q$, i.e., iff the equation $u^\top Q=\mathbf1^\top$ is solvable in $u$.

If $Q$ is invertible, there is nothing to prove.

Suppose $Q$ is singular. Let $r=\operatorname{rank}(R)$ and $q=\operatorname{rank}(Q)$. Then $r>0$ and $0<q<n$.
By [Schur product theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_product_theorem), $Q=R\circ R$ is positive semidefinite. By reindexing the rows and columns of $R$ and $Q$ if necessary, we may assume that the leading principal $q\times q$ submatrix of $Q$ has rank $q$ (and is thus positive definite). Let us express $R$ as a [Gram matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_matrix):
$$
R=\pmatrix{X_{q\times r}\\ Y_{(n-q)\times r}}\pmatrix{X^\top& Y^\top}
=\pmatrix{XX^\top&XY^\top\\ YX^\top&YY^\top}.
$$
Then
$$
Q=\pmatrix{(XX^\top)^{\circ2}&(XY^\top)^{\circ2}\\ (YX^\top)^{\circ2} &(YY^\top)^{\circ2}},
$$
where $(\cdot)^{\circ2}$ means Hadamard/entrywise matrix square. E.g. $(XX^\top)^{\circ2}=(XX^\top)\circ(XX^\top)$.

Since $Q$ has rank $q$, all $(q+1)$-rowed leading principal submatrices of $Q$ are singular. In particular,
$$
\pmatrix{(XX^\top)^{\circ2}&(Xy)^{\circ2}\\ (y^\top X^\top)^{\circ2}&1}\tag{$\dagger$}
$$
is singular for every column $y$ of $Y^\top$ (or for every row $y^\top$ of $Y$). So, we must have
$$
(y^\top X^\top)^{\circ2}
\ \big((XX^\top)^{\circ2}\big)^{-1}
\ (Xy)^{\circ2}=1.\tag{1}
$$
Moreover, as $Q$ has the same rank as $(XX^\top)^{\circ2}$, the second block column of $Q$ must be equal to the first block column of $Q$ right-multiplied by some matrix $M$. Thus
$$
Q=\pmatrix{(XX^\top)^{\circ2}& (XX^\top)^{\circ2}M\\ (YX^\top)^{\circ2} &(YX^\top)^{\circ2}M}
$$
where $M=\big((XX^\top)^{\circ2}\big)^{-1}(XY^\top)^{\circ2}$. So, in the equation $u^\top Q=\mathbf1^\top$, if we partition $u^\top$ and $\mathbf1^\top$ as $(v^\top,w^\top)$ and $(e^\top,f^\top)$ respectively, we have
$$
\begin{align}
&u^\top Q=\mathbf1^\top\\
\Leftrightarrow\quad&
u^\top Q\pmatrix{I_q&-M\\ 0&I_{n-q}}=\mathbf1^\top\pmatrix{I_q&-M\\ 0&I_{n-q}}\\
\Leftrightarrow\quad&
(v^\top,w^\top)
\pmatrix{(XX^\top)^{\circ2}&0\\ (YX^\top)^{\circ2} &0}
=(e^\top,f^\top)\pmatrix{I_q&-M\\ 0&I_{n-q}}\\
\Leftrightarrow\quad&
\begin{cases}
v^\top(XX^\top)^{\circ2}+w^\top(YX^\top)^{\circ2}=e^\top,\\
e^\top M=f^\top.
\end{cases}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Since $(XX^\top)^{\circ2}$ is positive definite (hence invertible), the first equation in $(2)$ is always solvable. It follows that $u^\top Q=\mathbf1^\top$ is solvable if and only if $e^\top M=f^\top$, i.e., if and only if
$e^\top\big((XX^\top)^{\circ2}\big)^{-1}\big((XY^\top)^{\circ2}\big)=f^\top$. Thus the problem now boils down to proving that for each column $y$ of $Y^\top$ (i.e., for each row $y^\top$ of $Y$), we have
$$
e^\top \big((XX^\top)^{\circ2}\big)^{-1} (Xy)^{\circ2}=1.\tag{3}
$$
Since $R$ has a diagonal of ones, $y$ is a unit vector. Pick any $r\times r$ orthogonal matrix $U$ whose first column is $y$. Define $Z=XU$ and let denote the $j$-th column of $Z$ by $z_j$. Then $z_1=Xy$. Condition $(1)$ and the statement-to-prove $(3)$ can be reformulated as
$$
\begin{align}
(z_1^{\circ2})^\top \big((ZZ^\top)^{\circ2}\big)^{-1} z_1^{\circ2}&=1,\tag{1a}\\
e^\top \big((ZZ^\top)^{\circ2}\big)^{-1} z_1^{\circ2}&=1.\tag{3a}
\end{align}
$$
If $Z$ has two or more columns (i.e., if $r\ge2$), then for any $j>1$, we consider the matrices
$$
\begin{aligned}
&R'=\pmatrix{Z\\ e_1^\top\\ e_j^\top}\pmatrix{Z^\top&e_1&e_j}
=\pmatrix{ZZ^\top&z_1&z_j\\ z_1^\top&1&0\\ z_j^\top&0&1},\\
&Q'=(R')^{\circ2}=\pmatrix{(ZZ^\top)^{\circ2}&(z_1)^{\circ2}&(z_j)^{\circ2}\\ ((z_1)^{\circ2})^\top&1&0\\ ((z_j)^{\circ2})^\top&0&1},\\
\end{aligned}
$$
Since $Q'$ is the entrywise square of the Gram matrix $R'$, it is positive semidefinite. However, as its leading principal $(q+1)\times(q+1)$ submatrix (i.e., the matrix $(\dagger)$) is singular, it cannot be positive definite. Hence $Q'$ is singular. In turn, the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) of $(ZZ^\top)^{\circ2}$ in $Q'$, namely, the $2\times2$ matrix
$$
\begin{aligned}
&I_2-
\pmatrix{((z_1)^{\circ2})^\top\\ ((z_j)^{\circ2})^\top}
\big((ZZ^\top)^{\circ2}\big)^{-1}
\pmatrix{(z_1)^{\circ2}&(z_j)^{\circ2}}\\
&=\pmatrix{0&-((z_1)^{\circ2})^\top(ZZ^\top)^{\circ2}\big)^{-1}(z_j)^{\circ2}\\
-((z_j)^{\circ2})^\top(ZZ^\top)^{\circ2}\big)^{-1}(z_1)^{\circ2}
&1-((z_j)^{\circ2})^\top(ZZ^\top)^{\circ2}\big)^{-1}(z_j)^{\circ2}},
\end{aligned}
$$
must be singular. Hence $(z_j^{\circ2})^\top \big((ZZ^\top)^{\circ2}\big)^{-1} z_1^{\circ2}=0$. So, regardless of whether $r\ge2$, we always have $(z_1^{\circ2})^\top \big((ZZ^\top)^{\circ2}\big)^{-1} z_1^{\circ2}=\left(\sum_{j=1}^r z_j^{\circ2}\right)^\top \big((ZZ^\top)^{\circ2}\big)^{-1} z_1^{\circ2}$. Hence $(1a)$ gives
$$
\left(\sum_{j=1}^r z_j^{\circ2}\right)^\top \big((ZZ^\top)^{\circ2}\big)^{-1} z_1^{\circ2}=1.
$$
Now, observe that each row of $Z$ is a unit vector. Thus $\sum_{j=1}^r z_j^{\circ2}=e$ and $(3a)$ follows.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I need to take time to understand it properly. I have some questions about the answer. 
(1) "We have $1^⊤Q^+Q=1^⊤$ if and only if the vector of ones lies inside the row space of Q" Does it mean there is an row vector of ones in $Q$? But it is not necessary. E.g. $Q=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0.5 & 0.5 \\
0.5 & 1 & 1 \\
0.5 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$
(2) "i.e., iff the equation $u^⊤Q=1^⊤$ is solvable in u". It seems not sufficient, as how to guarantee $u^⊤=1^⊤Q^+$?
(3) Could you explain more of how to get equation (1)?

Comment: @woody No, $1^\top$ is not necessarily a row of $Q$, but it must reside in the [*row space*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_and_column_spaces) of $Q$.

Comment: @woody (1) $u^\top Q=1^\top\Rightarrow 1^\top(Q^+Q)=(u^\top Q)(Q^+Q)=u^\top(QQ^+Q)=u^\top Q=1^\top$. (2) Call the block matrix $P$ . If $u^\top QP=1^\top P$, then $u^\top QPP^{-1}=1^\top PP^{-1}$ and hence $u^\top Q=1^\top$.

Comment: I have two more questions. "If we partition $u^\top$ and $\mathbf1^\top$ as $(v^\top,w^\top)$ and $(e^\top,f^\top)$ respectively", does it mean $e^\top=1^\top,f^\top=1^\top$? If $e^\top$ in (3) is $1^\top$ and we want to prove (3), do we need to prove $\left(\sum_{j=1}^r z_j^{\circ2}\right)^\top=1^\top$ in the last equation $\left(\sum_{j=1}^r z_j^{\circ2}\right)^\top \big((ZZ^\top)^{\circ2}\big)^{-1} z_1^{\circ2}=1$?

Comment: @woody No. $\mathbf 1^\top,e^\top$ and $f^\top$ are three vectors of ones, with $n,q$ and $n-q$ elements respectively. Since they have different sizes, they are not identical to each other. The $e^\top$ in equation $(3)$ is *not* a typo. It is indeed $e^\top$, not $\mathbf 1^\top$. For a sanity check, observe that $e^\top$ is $1\times q$, $\big((XX^\top)^{\circ2}\big)^{-1}$ is $q\times q$ and $X$ is $q\times r$ and $y$ is $r\times1$. At the bottom of the answer, $\sum_{j=1}^rz_j^{\circ2}$ is a $q\times1$ vector. It is equal to $e$, not $\mathbf1$.

Comment: Yes, let $\mathbf{1}_q^\top=e^\top$ be a row vector of $q$ ones. Then, is this the overall logic?

$$\begin{align*}&\mathbf1^\top Q^+Q=\mathbf1^\top\\\Leftarrow\ &u^\top Q=\mathbf1^\top\\\Leftarrow\ &\mathbf{1}_q^\top ((XX^\top)^{\circ2})^{-1} (Xy)^{\circ2}=1 \tag{3}\\\Leftarrow\ &\mathbf{1}_q^\top ((ZZ^\top)^{\circ2})^{-1} z_1^{\circ2}=1\tag{3a}\\\Leftarrow\ &\left(\sum_{j=1}^r z_j^{\circ2}\right)^\top ((ZZ^\top)^{\circ2})^{-1} z_1^{\circ2}=1 \\\Leftarrow\ &\left(\sum_{j=1}^r z_j^{\circ2}\right)^\top=\mathbf{1}_q^\top\ \text{for every}\ y\\\Leftarrow\ &?\end{align*}$$

Comment: @woody Not exactly. Under the assumption that $Q$ is singular, quite a number of lines in your previous comment are actually shown to be equivalent, but for the purpose of proving $\mathbf1^\top QQ^+=\mathbf1^\top$, it doesn't hurt to consider the direction of inference that you have described. At any rate, the “?” on the last line of your comment has already been explained in the last paragraph of my answer: *“observe that each row of $Z$ is a unit vector. Thus $\sum_{j=1}^r z_j^{\circ2}=e$”*.

Comment: I have a last question. For the second row and column block of $Q$, how to prove $(YX^\top)^{\circ2}M=(YX^\top)^{\circ2}\big((XX^\top)^{\circ2}\big)^{-1}(XY^\top)^{\circ2}=(YY^\top)^{\circ2}$?

Comment: @woody By applying Gaussian elimination to $Q$ or by considering the Schur complement of $(XX^\top)^{\circ2}$ in $Q$.

Comment: By performing a block Gaussian elimination on the matrix $Q$, we have
$$
Q\pmatrix{I & -([(XX^\top)^{\circ2}]^{-1}(XY^\top)^{\circ2} \\
0 & I}
=\pmatrix{(XX^\top)^{\circ2} & 0 \\
(YX^\top)^{\circ2} & Q/(XX^\top)^{\circ2}}
$$
where $Q/(XX^\top)^{\circ2}=(YY^\top)^{\circ2}-(YX^\top)^{\circ2}[(XX^\top)^{\circ2}]^{-1}(XY^\top)^{\circ2}$ is  the Schur complement of the block $(XX^\top)^{\circ2}$ of the matrix $Q$.  However, how to prove $Q/(XX^\top)^{\circ2}$ is a zero matrix?

Comment: @woody By assumption, $(XX^\top)^{\circ2}$ has the same rank as $Q$.

Comment: Yes, I think there is $\text{rank}(Q)=\text{rank}((XX^\top)^{\circ2})\Rightarrow \text{rank}(Q/(XX^\top)^{\circ2})=0\Rightarrow|Q/(XX^\top)^{\circ2})|=0$. But then, how to get $Q/(XX^\top)^{\circ2}$ being a zero matrix?

Comment: @woody For any block matrix $Q=\pmatrix{A&B\\ C&D}$, we have $\operatorname{rank}(A)\le\operatorname{rank}\pmatrix{A\\ C}\le\operatorname{rank}(Q)$. Therefore, if $A$ and $Q$ have the same rank, we must have $\operatorname{rank}\pmatrix{A\\ C}=\operatorname{rank}(Q)$. Since $\operatorname{range}\pmatrix{A\\ C}$ is a subspace of $\operatorname{range}(Q)$, the two column spaces must be equal. In particular, all columns of $\pmatrix{B\\ D}$ are linear combinations of columns of $\operatorname{range}\pmatrix{A\\ C}$. Hence $\pmatrix{B\\ D}=\pmatrix{A\\ C}M$ for some $M$, i.e., $B=AM$ and $D=CM$...

Comment: ... So, if $A$ happens to be invertible, then from $B=AM$ we obtain $M=A^{-1}B$. Hence $D=CM=CA^{-1}B$. In our case, this translates to $(YY^\top)^{\circ2}=(YX^\top)^{\circ2}\big((YY^\top)^{\circ2}\big)^{-1}(XY^\top)^{\circ2}$.

Comment: I finally get it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

This is not a new answer. After learning @user1551's answer for a week, I reorganized the proof and added some details.

When $\mathbf{Q}$ is of full rank, $\mathbf{Q}^+=\mathbf{Q}^{-1}$, obviously, there is $\mathbf1^\top\mathbf{Q}^{-1}\mathbf{Q}=\mathbf1^\top$.

When $\mathbf{Q}$ is singular, suppose $\text{rank}(\mathbf{Q})=q$.  Suppose the $i_1,\dots,i_q$ rows of $\mathbf{Q}$ forms a maximal linearly independent group in the row space. Let $i_{q+1},\dots,i_n$ be the indices of the other rows. Sort the rows and columns of $\mathbf{Q}$ in the order of $i_1,\dots,i_q,i_{q+1},\dots,i_n$ and denote the sorted matrix as $Q$, whose leading principal $q\times q$ submatrix has full rank.

Let $R$ be the correlation matrix satisfying $Q=R\circ R$. Suppose the rank of $R$ is $r$. Since $R$ is a correlation matrix, it is a [Gram matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_matrix), which is a symmetric matrix of inner products. Thus, $R$ and $Q$ can be express as
$$
R=\pmatrix{
X_{q\times r} \\ 
Y_{(n-q)\times r}}
\pmatrix{X^\top& Y^\top}
=\pmatrix{XX^\top&XY^\top\\ YX^\top&YY^\top},\quad
Q=R^{\circ2}=\pmatrix{(XX^\top)^{\circ2}&(XY^\top)^{\circ2}\\ (YX^\top)^{\circ2} &(YY^\top)^{\circ2}}
$$
where $(\cdot)^{\circ2}$ means element-wise square and $(XX^\top)^{\circ2}$ is a $q\times q$ full-rank submatrix. Since the column vectors in the first column partition of $Q$ is maximally linearly independent, the second column partition of $Q$ can be represented as a linear combination of them. Since $(XX^\top)^{\circ2}$  is invertible, let $M=((XX^\top)^{\circ2})^{-1}(XY^\top)^{\circ2}$. We have
$$
Q=\pmatrix{(XX^\top)^{\circ2} & (XX^\top)^{\circ2}M \\
(YX^\top)^{\circ2} & (YX^\top)^{\circ2}M}
$$
Since the diagonal elements of $XX^\top$ are ones, the row vectors of $X$ are unit vectors. Let $y_i$ denote any $i$-th ($1\le i\le n-q$) column of $Y^\top$. Since $\pmatrix{
(XX^\top)^{\circ2} & (Xy_i)^{\circ2} \\ (y_i^\top X^\top)^{\circ2} & 1}$ does not have full rank, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\begin{matrix}
(XX^\top)^{\circ2} & (Xy_i)^{\circ2} \\
(y_i^\top X^\top)^{\circ2} & 1 \\
\end{matrix}\right| = \left|(XX^\top)^{\circ2}\right|\left|1 - (y_i^\top X^\top)^{\circ2}\big((XX^\top)^{\circ2}\big)^{-1}(Xy_i)^{\circ2}\right| = 0 \\
\Longrightarrow\quad (y_i^\top X^\top)^{\circ2}\big((XX^\top)^{\circ2}\big)^{-1}(Xy_i)^{\circ2}=1\tag{1}\end{align}
$$
Since $y_i^\top y_i=1$, let $U_{r\times r}$ be any orthogonal matrix with the first column being $y_i$. Let $Z_{q\times r}=(z_1,\dots,z_r)=XU$, where $z_1=Xy_i$. Since an orthogonal transformation  preserves the length of a vector, the row vectors of $Z$ are unit vectors, i.e., $\sum_{j=1}^r z_j^{\circ2}=\mathbf1_q$. By substituting $X=ZU^\top$ into (1), we have

$$
(z_1^{\circ2})^\top \big((ZZ^\top)^{\circ2}\big)^{-1} z_1^{\circ2}=1\tag{1a}
$$
When $r\ge2$, let
$$
\begin{aligned}
&R_{(q+2)\times(q+2)}'=\pmatrix{Z\\ e_1^\top\\ e_j^\top}\pmatrix{Z^\top&e_1&e_j}
=\pmatrix{ZZ^\top&z_1&z_j\\ z_1^\top&1&0\\ z_j^\top&0&1} \\
&Q_{(q+2)\times(q+2)}'=(R')^{\circ2}=\pmatrix{(ZZ^\top)^{\circ2}&z_1^{\circ2}&z_j^{\circ2}\\ (z_1^{\circ2})^\top&1&0\\ (z_j^{\circ2})^\top&0&1} \\
\end{aligned}
$$
where $e_j$ is a unit vector with the $j$-th element being one. Since $R'$ is a [Gram matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_matrix) which is positive semidefinite, according to the [Schur product theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_product_theorem), $Q'$ is positive semidefinite. Since the determent of the leading principal submatrix of $Q'$ is
$$
\left|\begin{matrix}
(ZZ^\top)^{\circ2}&z_1^{\circ2} \\
(z_1^{\circ2})^\top&1 \\
\end{matrix}\right|
=\left|\begin{matrix}
(XX^\top)^{\circ2} & (Xy_i)^{\circ2} \\
(y_i^\top X^\top)^{\circ2} & 1 \\
\end{matrix}\right|=0
$$
$Q'$ does not have full rank. Since $(ZZ^\top)^{\circ2}$ is positive definite, the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) of $(ZZ^\top)^{\circ2}$ of $Q'$ is not positive definite. Thus, we have ($(\text{a1})$ is used)
$$
\begin{aligned}
\left|Q'/(ZZ^\top)^{\circ2}\right|
=& \left| I_2-
\pmatrix{(z_1^{\circ2})^\top\\ (z_j^{\circ2})^\top}
\pmatrix{(ZZ^\top)^{\circ2}}^{-1}
\pmatrix{z_1^{\circ2}&z_j^{\circ2}}\right| \\
=& \left|\begin{matrix}
0 & -(z_1^{\circ2})^\top[(ZZ^\top)^{\circ2}]^{-1}z_j^{\circ2}\\
-(z_j^{\circ2})^\top[(ZZ^\top)^{\circ2}]^{-1}z_1^{\circ2}
& 1-(z_j^{\circ2})^\top[(ZZ^\top)^{\circ2}]^{-1}z_j^{\circ2}\end{matrix}\right| \\
=& -\left((z_1^{\circ2})^\top[(ZZ^\top)^{\circ2}]^{-1}z_j^{\circ2}\right)^2=0 \\
\Rightarrow \quad & (z_j^{\circ2})^\top[(ZZ^\top)^{\circ2}]^{-1}z_1^{\circ2}=0 \\
\Rightarrow \quad & \sum_{j=2}^r(z_j^{\circ2})^\top[(ZZ^\top)^{\circ2}]^{-1}z_1^{\circ2}=0 \\
\Rightarrow \quad & \sum_{j=1}^r(z_j^{\circ2})^\top[(ZZ^\top)^{\circ2}]^{-1}z_1^{\circ2}=1 \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Since $\sum_{j=1}^r z_j^{\circ2}=\mathbf1_q$, we have $\mathbf1_q^\top\left((ZZ^\top)^{\circ2}\right)^{-1}z_1^{\circ2}=1$. By substituting $Z=XU$ and $z_1=Xy_i$, we have $\mathbf1_q^\top\left((XX^\top)^{\circ2}\right)^{-1}(Xy_i)^{\circ2}=1$. Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
&\mathbf1_q^\top\left((XX^\top)^{\circ2}\right)^{-1}\pmatrix{(Xy_1)^{\circ2}&\cdots&(Xy_{n-q})^{\circ2}} \\
=&\mathbf1_q^\top\left((XX^\top)^{\circ2}\right)^{-1}(XY)^{\circ2}=\mathbf1_q^\top M=\mathbf1_{n-q}^\top \tag{2a}\end{align}
$$
Since $\text{rank}(\begin{bmatrix}(XX^\top)^{\circ2} & (XY^\top)^{\circ2}\end{bmatrix})=\text{rank}(\begin{bmatrix}(XX^\top)^{\circ2} & (XY^\top)^{\circ2} & \mathbf1_q\end{bmatrix})=q$, the system of linear equations
$$
\begin{bmatrix}(XX^\top)^{\circ2} & (XY^\top)^{\circ2}\end{bmatrix}u_{n\times1}=\mathbf1_q \tag{2b}
$$
with the $n$ variables being elements of $u$ has solutions. By rearranging $\text{(2a)}$ and $\text{(2b)}$ in matrix form, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf1_n^\top\pmatrix{I_q&-M\\ 0 & I_{n-q}} 
=& u^\top\pmatrix{(XX^\top)^{\circ2}&0\\ (YX^\top)^{\circ2} &0} \\
=& u^\top\pmatrix{(XX^\top)^{\circ2}&(XY^\top)^{\circ2}\\ (YX^\top)^{\circ2} &(YY^\top)^{\circ2}}\pmatrix{I_q&-\big((XX^\top)^{\circ2}\big)^{-1}(XY^\top)^{\circ2}\\ 0&I_{n-q}} \\
=& u^\top Q\pmatrix{I_q&-M\\ 0&I_{n-q}} \\
\end{align}
$$
Since $\pmatrix{I_q&-M\\ 0&I_{n-q}}$ has a determinant of one and is therefore invertible, we have that the system of linear equations $\mathbf1^\top=u^\top Q$  has solutions. Thus, $\mathbf1^\top Q^+Q = u^\top QQ^+Q = u^\top Q = \mathbf1^\top$ has solutions, and thus, $\mathbf1^\top Q^+Q = \mathbf1^\top$ holds regardless of $u$.

Since $Q$ is obtained from $\mathbf{Q}$ by row and column-switching transformations.  By denoting the corresponding elementary matrices as $T_1,\dots,T_s$, we have $Q=T_s\cdots T_1\mathbf{Q}T_1\cdots T_s$. Since any $T_i$ is an orthogonal matrix, there is $(T_i\mathbf{Q}T_i)^+=T_i^\top\mathbf{Q}^+T_i^\top$, and since

$T_i^{-1}=T_i=T_i^\top$, we have
$$
\mathbf1^\top Q^+Q = \mathbf1^\top (T_s\cdots T_1\mathbf{Q}T_1\cdots T_s)^+(T_s\cdots T_1\mathbf{Q}T_1\cdots T_s) =\mathbf1^\top T_s\cdots T_1\mathbf{Q}^+\mathbf{Q}T_1\cdots T_s=\mathbf1^\top
$$
i.e., $(T_s\cdots T_1\mathbf{Q}^+\mathbf{Q}T_1\cdots T_s)$ is a matrix with each column sums to one. Since $\mathbf{Q}^+\mathbf{Q}$ is obtained from it by row and column-switching transformations, the summation over each column of $\mathbf{Q}^+\mathbf{Q}$ is still one, i.e., $\mathbf1^\top\mathbf{Q}^+\mathbf{Q}=\mathbf1^\top$.